# conda install python=3.6 UnsatisfiableError

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-3.6

I currently have Python 3.5.2 installed via Anaconda Continuum. I'm trying to upgrade to Python 3.6 but I'm getting the below error when I try to run `conda install python=3.6`:

```
UnsatisfiableError:
The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- enum34 -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.5*
- python ==3.6.0
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729329/python3-cannot-import-dlib-but-installed-using-conda/48732498. I am a nowise and I don't understand what happened underneath - but this worked for dlib installation issues.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have enum34 installed, which requires 2.6-3.5. Installing Python 3.6 is thus not possible without either updating enum34 to see if newer versions support 3.6, removing enum34, or installing Python 3.6 in a new environment.

Comment: Thanks - uninstalled it with `conda uninstall enum34` and now able to run `conda install python=3.6`

Comment: I ran into other conflicts and they didn't all get listed the first time I tried to upgrade to 3.6

Comment: I have this same issue, though uninstalling enum34 now gives me "ImportError: No module named enum"

Comment: @EmilyK I'm getting the same error. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @NirvanAnjirbag I honestly don't remember... I might have just uninstalled my Anaconda altogether and just downloaded 3.6 fresh.

Comment: I am getting the below error when trying to install dlib:  UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found                                                                                                                                                 
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

  - dlib -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
  - dlib -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']

Comment: Could not remove the package and then discovered this link - found it working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729329/python3-cannot-import-dlib-but-installed-using-conda/48732498

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error but a  bit different:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - argcomplete -> python 3.5*
  - python ==3.6
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

You can try removing offending packages like this:

```
conda remove argcomplete conda-manager
```

Sometimes this will keep showing new offending packages. In that case, I would just remove Anaconda installation from the path, delete folder and re-install.

However, ultimately I just found that Python 3.6 is not worth the trouble yet due to incompatibility with TensorFlow, OpenCV, VS2015 etc. So I ended up making Python 3.5 as default by doing this in Anaconda:

```
conda install python=3.5
```

This command will overwrite your Python version in conda with 3.5. Doing this fixed most of the errors I was facing.

Comment: "Sometime this will keep showing new offending packages. In that case, I would just remove Anaconda installation from the path, delete folder and re-install."

This is what happened to me.. To preserve my Environments, I shared each environment as 'environment.yml' file, and later on after installing a fresh latest version anaconda, I imported my environments from these files. Details how to do it: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment

Answer (score 0):

if anybody founds difficulty in upgradation of python like conda install python=3.6 UnsatisfiableError due to some other library like env, lasagne etc.In that case just remove that library using the command
conda remove library name and again do the installation by using command
conda update python