# Unable to install shogun on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, conda, shogun

I have installed anaconda3 on my ubuntu 16.04. I am now trying to install shogun toolbox. I am typing the following command:-

```
conda install -c conda-forge shogun
```

And I am getting the following error:-

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

  - blaze
  - python 3.6*
  - shogun

Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of anaconda and python are you using

Comment: python 3.6.1 and anaconda 4.4.0

Comment: Have you tried conda's suggestion and used conda info?

Comment: conda info shogun gives following result:-NoPackagesFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - shogun

Comment: Also is [this process](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/install#ubuntu) not enough? Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: It's not working. I have tried it.

Comment: What version of `conda` are you using? With 4.3.25, I get the output `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pytables -> hdf5 1.8.9
  - pytables -> lzo 2.06
  - shogun -> shogun-cpp 6.0.0 -> lzo 2.09` which shows the conflict is in the PyTables package, which is a dependency of blaze. Do you need to have blaze and shogun in the same environment?

Comment: I don't think I need blaze.

Answer (score 0):

Though not exact match of the question asked but might help in understanding the Unsatisfiable Error meaning.

[conda install python=3.6 UnsatisfiableError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075581/conda-install-python-3-6-unsatisfiableerror)

Answer (score 0):

do:
    conda uninstall pytables 
then:
    conda install shogun