# Failed package installation in Python

Tags: python, failed-installation, mrjob

I am trying to install the Mrjob package for Python and I get the following error:

```
AJs-MacBook-Pro-13:~ aj$ conda install -c asmeurer mrjob
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - mrjob -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which python version you are using?

Comment: similar error @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075581/conda-install-python-3-6-unsatisfiableerror

Comment: I actually had to navigate to the python installation folder and use "pip install mrjob"

Answer (score 0):

steps::
--open your command prompt and change your directory to C:\Python27\Scripts
--make sure that you have install 'pip' or 'easy_install'
--if you have pip install then directly give command

pip install mrjob 
or
easy_install mrjob

it will take few minutes to install the  package .once its get completed
the check that whether that package is install or not with following command

import mrjob