# Python3: Cannot import dlib (But installed using conda)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dlib

I used `conda install -c conda-forge dlib` to successfully install **dlib** but when using `import dlib` I got **ModuleNotFoundError**

I don't want to go all the way to manually build **dilb** using `pip install dlib` as I saw a lot of people not having problem installing **dlib** from **conda-forge**.

I'm using python 3.6.2 though.

Comment: Just type `pip install dlib` and see what happens. It's only going to take you a second.

Comment: @DavisKing thank you. Solved for now. It turns out that I didn't properly building and setting up Dlib library. I followed this [tutorial](Install Dlib on Windows) and making sure that I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 (was using update 2 previously). Now It works using `conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.7`

Answer (score 1):

Solved for now. It turns out that I didn't properly building and setting up Dlib library. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-windows/) and making sure that I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 (was using update 2 previously). Now It works using `conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.7`