# Unsatisfiable error conda-installing MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql-python, conda

I'm trying to install MySQL-python with conda. I get the following error:

```
> conda install MySQL-python
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - mysql-python -> python 2.7* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I don't even understand which is the conflict... maybe python 2.7 and 3.7 cannot coexist?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this error message is a little hard to decrypt. Have you tried looking into [similar error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075581/conda-install-python-3-6-unsatisfiableerror) which may shed some light on the issue? Python 2.7 and 3.7 can normally co-exist just fine. You may need to specify which one is being used when creating your Anaconda environment. I would suggest using the command `conda info <package>` on mysql-python and see what dependencies are returned.