# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment

Tags: python, version, python-venv

I am trying to install a conda package that appears to require Python 3.7. My base environment uses Python 3.8. I successfully created and activated a virtual environment with version 3.7. However, when I try to install that package in the environment, I still get the error below. How can I solve this problem to successfully install this package?

**(venv)(base)C:\Users\MyUsername> python**
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

**(venv)(base)C:\Users\MyUsername> conda install arcpy -c esri**
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- arcpy -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

Comment: Is Anaconda installed to your venv or are you using it globally?

Comment: I believe I am using it globally? I am new to this, but I have been using Spyder with Anaconda for a few months

Comment: I just tried "pip install conda" in the venv, but that errored stating that conda can only be used in root environments

Comment: You're right... try `conda install python=3.7`

Comment: That yields a PackagesNotFoundError. Does this mean python 3.7 isn't installed on my computer? It looks like it is, and I was able to create the venv with that version

Comment: It's cause Anaconda is using your global Python package, not your venv one. I don't know the answer, but this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075581/conda-install-python-3-6-unsatisfiableerror

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having a similar problem with installing the ArcGIS API for Python.

Comment: @Foggy I did not. What is the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: @justabeginner - I suspect my root environment was corrupted. No matter what I tried the installation failed. I tried again on a different computer with a newer installation Anaconda installation and the installation proceeded as expected. I haven’t finished retrying on the original corrupted installation yet. I am restarting wit a new install of anaconda there.

Comment: @justabeginner The issue did not resolve with a fresh install. `UnsatisfiableError:
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.` I don't see any way forward on this. Moving this to an ESRI forum question.